# Global Exception Handling in Android (NullPointerException not caught)

Tags: android, exception, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement global exception handling in my Android application, but I can't handle NullPointerException.

In my onCreate method in Application sub-class:

```
@Override
      public void onCreate() 
      {
        super.onCreate();       

        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UncaughtExceptionHandler() 
        {

            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread arg0, Throwable arg1) 
            {
                Log.v("UncaughtException", arg1.getCause().getMessage());
            }

        });

      }
```

In onCreate method of my Main Activity if I try:

```
int n = 10 / 0; //The log show me divide by zero exception

int[] vet = new int[] {1,2,3};
int _n = vet[5]; // The log show me index out of bounds exception

But if I try:
String s = null;

s.substring(0, 10); //The Application crash but nothing is logged
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: don't you catch it somewhere else ? Also, for testing, you can simply `throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Bla");`. And if your handler is not called, there should be a big stacktrace in the log

Comment: Aparently, the handler is not been called just in the case of a NullPointerException

Comment: coudl it be that `arg1.getCause()` is null ? did you put a breakpoint in your handler to make sure it is not called ?